# Provisioning Profile & APNS issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, archive, provisioning-profile

Using a provisioning profile to make an archive for an app, I have the following case:
On the `Apple Developer Portal` under `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`
I can see this information for myProfile

```
Type:
    iOS Distribution
Enabled Services:
    Game Center, In-App Purchase, Push Notifications
```

But when using myProfile later to generate the app archive
The `aps-environment production` does not appear in the `Binary and Entitlements` list.
How can that happen? What did I do wrong?

Doesn't "Push Notifications" implies "aps-environment"?

Comment: Did you download the provisioning profile after enabling push notifications in the portal?

Comment: Yes. And I even remade the provisioning profile, several times. Does the provisioning profile, on the portal, seems OK here? If YES, it would be during the download, or in Xcode that there is a problem?

Comment: After downloading the provisioning profile, did you double-click it? Besides that, I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Yes I did, in order to install it to Xcode.

Comment: @Michel Having exactly the same issue here. Did you solve that?

Comment: Yes, I "solved" that. I put solve between quotes because you may not call that "solve". Here is what I did: after spending too many hours on this, I decided to give up (at least temporarily), and went to generate the distribution provisioning profile for the appStore. When I made the archive with this new profile, I was lucky to see that the problem was now solved. Do not ask me how it got solved, I just don't know. This is all my story; I suppose I was lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Please reload all certificate from Xcode  and check it again.

Steps for reload all certificate from Xcode

- Xcode menu => Preferences => Accounts
- Select the Apple ID in the left panel.
- Click the View Details button on the right.
- In the pop-over that follows click the round refresh arrow. The lists
  will refresh after the download from the Member Center finishes. This
  can take a few minutes.
- The provisioning profiles can then be selected in a Mac project under
  Build Settings => Code Signing => Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Thanks, though I think I have done that already n times. I just redid it now, carefully following your steps. And unfortunately I still have the same result.

Comment: Following the steps in the answer given by Mahesh, after the refresh; if I look at the list of profiles, I can see only:
“keychain, inAppPurchase, gameCenter” in the Entitlements on the right, for myProfile. Shouldn’t “push” also be there?